# Firestore token doesn't update in security rules after setting custom claim

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

TLDR;

1. Setup firestore security rules based on custom claim.
2. Cloud firestore user is created by phone auth.
3. Cloud function triggers on create user and adds a custom claim role- admin. An entry is updated in realtime database to indicate the claim update.
4. Listen to updates to realtime database in the client and call `user.getIdToken(true);` after custom claim is updated.
5. Able to see the added custom claim in the code.
6. Unable to read a document in firestore due to missing permission(custom claim).
7. Refresh the browser page, able to read the doc now.

---

I have a cloud function that adds a custom claim `role - admin` on user create.

```
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const customClaims = {
      role: 'admin',
    };
    // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
      .then(() => {
        // Update real-time database to notify client to force refresh.
        const metadataRef = admin.database().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);
        // Set the refresh time to the current UTC timestamp.
        // This will be captured on the client to force a token refresh.
        return metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
});
```

I listen to change events in realtime database to detect updates to custom claim for a user.

```
let callback = null;
let metadataRef = null;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  // Remove previous listener.
  if (callback) {
    metadataRef.off('value', callback);
  }
  // On user login add new listener.
  if (user) {
    // Check if refresh is required.
    metadataRef = firebase.database().ref('metadata/' + user.uid + '/refreshTime');
    callback = (snapshot) => {
      // Force refresh to pick up the latest custom claims changes.
      // Note this is always triggered on first call. Further optimization could be
      // added to avoid the initial trigger when the token is issued and already contains
      // the latest claims.
      user.getIdToken(true);
    };
    // Subscribe new listener to changes on that node.
    metadataRef.on('value', callback);
  }
});
```

I have the following security rules on cloud firestore.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{role}/{document=**} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null &&
                        request.auth.token.role == role;
    }
  }
}
```

After the user is created, my cloud function triggers and adds the custom claim `role = admin`.

As a result of `user.getIdToken(true);` the token is refreshed on my client and I am able to see the set custom claim.

When I try to get a document that the user should be able to read, I get a permission denied by cloud firestore security rules.

When I refresh the browser page, I am able to read the documents in the path.

I am expecting that to be able to access the firebase doc without having to refresh the browser. Is this a possibility?

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my approach/expectation?

Answer (score 1):

It can take longer than you think for the token to be propagated.  I use custom claims extensively - what I have found to work is to setup `.onIdTokenChanged()` to track uid & token updates, and *then* explicitly call `.getIdTokenResult(true)` to update my local token.  Only after both are complete can you make customClaim secured calls to Firestore and/or RTDB.

Comment: I will add - there have been some updates recently to Firestore that seem to address this directly.  I have *not* tried them, as the solution here works for me.

Comment: Listening to `onIdTokenChanged()` and calling `.getIdTokenResult(true)` unfortunately, did not work in my case. 

I see the claim inside `.getIdTokenResult(true).then`, but I still get `Missing or insufficient permission` error when I try to read a document inside `.getIdTokenResult(true).then`.